# Thymeleaf didn't see objects from Spring

Tags: java, spring

My template do not see objects, passed from Spring.

My code:

```
public class PublicModelAndView extends ModelAndView {

    @Autowired
    TemplateModulesHandler templateModulesHandler;

    public void init() {

        setViewName("index");
        CSSProcessor cSSProcessor = new CSSProcessor();
        cSSProcessor.setSiteRegion("public");
        super.addObject("CSSProcessor", cSSProcessor);

        JSProcessor jSProcessor = new JSProcessor();
        super.addObject("JSProcessor", jSProcessor);

        templateModulesHandler.setPublicModelAndView(this);

    }

}
```

Contoller's code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
public class IndexPage {

    @Autowired
    PublicModelAndView publicModelAndView;
    @Autowired
    OurServicesBean ourServicesBean;
    @Autowired
    PortfolioBean portfolioBean;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView indexPage() {

        publicModelAndView.setTemplate("publicSiteIndexPage");
        publicModelAndView.addObject("pageTitle", "TITLE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        publicModelAndView.addObject("ourServices", ourServicesBean.getMenu());
        publicModelAndView.addObject("portfolioWorkTypes", portfolioBean.getWorkTypes());
        publicModelAndView.addObject("portfolioWorks", portfolioBean.getWorks());

        return publicModelAndView;

    }

}
```

Main template's code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      >
    <head th:include="headerAndFooter/fragments/header :: publicSiteHeader">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        hello!
    </body>

</html>
```

Fragment's code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

    <head th:fragment="publicSiteHeader">

        <title>${pageTitle}</title>

        <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script src="<?= SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH ?>/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

As result I do not see value of the object pageTitle, but I see in page output code like

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>

        <title>${pageTitle}</title>
```

Why thymeleaf didn't paste value of the pageTitle to between title tag's open and close?

The same code works good with JSP, but do not work with thymeleaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thymeleaf is not JSP, so that's why your template does not work as you expect.

Look here http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#using-texts and use something like:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

    <title th:text="#{pageTitle}">page title</title>
```

Edited - my solution is for localised texts which is good practice anyway. if you want to use content of variable than use $.

Comment: you are welcome :), if you are using it with Spring and Eclipse do not forget to check also  thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3 add-on and eclipse plugin from https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-eclipse-plugin . The nice tutorial you can find here https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-itutorial.

Comment: Thanks! I have another question... Can you look a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28067861/how-to-call-objects-method-from-thymeleaf ?