# How to call object's method from Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

My template do not see objects, passed from Spring.

My code:

```
public class PublicModelAndView extends ModelAndView {

    @Autowired
    TemplateModulesHandler templateModulesHandler;

    public void init() {

        setViewName("index");
        CSSProcessor cSSProcessor = new CSSProcessor();
        cSSProcessor.setSiteRegion("public");
        super.addObject("CSSProcessor", cSSProcessor);

        JSProcessor jSProcessor = new JSProcessor();
        super.addObject("JSProcessor", jSProcessor);

        templateModulesHandler.setPublicModelAndView(this);

    }

}
```

Contoller's code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
public class IndexPage {

    @Autowired
    PublicModelAndView publicModelAndView;
    @Autowired
    OurServicesBean ourServicesBean;
    @Autowired
    PortfolioBean portfolioBean;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView indexPage() {

        publicModelAndView.setTemplate("publicSiteIndexPage");
        publicModelAndView.addObject("ourServices", ourServicesBean.getMenu());
        publicModelAndView.addObject("portfolioWorkTypes", portfolioBean.getWorkTypes());
        publicModelAndView.addObject("portfolioWorks", portfolioBean.getWorks());

        return publicModelAndView;

    }

}
```

Main template's code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      >
    <head th:include="headerAndFooter/fragments/header :: publicSiteHeader">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        hello!
    </body>

</html>
```

Fragment's code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

    <head th:fragment="publicSiteHeader">

        <title>SOME TITLE</title>

         ${CSSProcessor.setDebugCaller("Public")}
         ${CSSProcessor.setSiteRegion("public")}
         ${CSSProcessor.addCSS("/css/main.css")}
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

As result I see code of the method calling, like

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>

        <title>SOME TITLE</title>

         ${CSSProcessor.setDebugCaller("Public")}
         ${CSSProcessor.setSiteRegion("public")}
         ${CSSProcessor.addCSS("/css/main.css")}
```

Why thymeleaf didn't call methods, but print this text at the output page? In example from http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html method calling has same syntax, like

```
${person.createCompleteName()}
```

The same code works good with JSP, but do not work with thymeleaf.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That can be done in Thymeleaf in two ways:

First is to use special  for Thymeleaf:

```
<head th:fragment="publicSiteHeader">

    <title>SOME TITLE</title>

     <th:block th:text="${CSSProcessor.setDebugCaller("Public")}"/>
     <th:block th:text="${CSSProcessor.setSiteRegion("public")}"/>
     <th:block th:text="${CSSProcessor.addCSS("/css/main.css")}"/>
</head>
```

And the second way is:

```
<head th:fragment="publicSiteHeader" th:inline="text">

    <title>SOME TITLE</title>

     [["${CSSProcessor.setDebugCaller("Public")}"]]
     [["${CSSProcessor.setSiteRegion("public")}"]]
     [["${CSSProcessor.addCSS("/css/main.css")}"]]
</head>
```

For natural template processing second option is more preferable. More info about inlining can be found here: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#inlining

Answer (score 5):

You can call methods via thymeleaf but it is not a good practice. The thymeleaf has different philosophy than JSP - it tries to use valid HTML templates. And to be honest: Calling methods in JSP is not good practice as well. But I am not your judge, so to call a method use non visible span or div, try something like:

```
<span th:text="${myvariable.myfunct()}" />
```

Comment: It would be nice to hear out why it is not a good practice; and your suggested method does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Thymeleaf does not work like JSP. It works by extending existing HTML elements with new attributes prefixed by "th:". And you can reference variables (and therefore call method on them) only in theses extra-attributes.

E.g. `<p th:text="${contentOfTheParagraph}" />` will work with thymeleaf

But `<p>${contentOfTheParagraph}"</p>` will not.

Comment: Thats not quiet true. You can use th:block or th:inline for doing <p>[[${contentOfTheParagraph}"]]</p> or <p><th:block>${contentOfTheParagraph}"</th:block</p>. Check my answer below.