# How to generate JSON custom data-attribute using thymeleaf?

Tags: json, thymeleaf, custom-data-attribute

I have a requirement to embed JSON as custom data-attribute using thymeleaf. I have hacky working solution like this.

```
<th:block th:fragment="myFragment(val)">
    <div th:attr="data-json='{&quot;x&quot;:&quot;'+ ${val}+'-x&quot;}'"></div>
</th:block>
```

Result HTML

```
<div data-json="{"x": "abc-x"}"></div>
```

Embedding JSON template with `&quot;` is not a good solution.

Is there a way to generate JSON with a cleaner fragment in thymeleaf? If so, can someone share such a fix?

FYI, I have `@Data (lombok)` and `@JsonInclude (jackson library)` at disposal in Java model but I don't want to update my model as the thymeleaf fragment is independent of the model (depends only on val).

Comment: I ended up invoking method on the model to return JSON string back. It is discussed on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28067861/how-to-call-objects-method-from-thymeleaf.
View calling a method on the model is not the right approach but it is better than having convoluted json formatter in view.
Please let me know if someone has a better way of solving this? Thanks.