# How can I call getters from model passed to Thymeleaf like parameter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I add object to ModelAndView

```
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
User currentUser = getUser();
model.addObject("currentUser", currentUser);
```

User model:

```
public class User {
    private String msisdn;
    private double balance;
    private double trafficResidue;
    private Map<String, String> variables;

    public String getMsisdn() {
        return msisdn;
    }

    public void setMsisdn(String msisdn) {
        this.msisdn = msisdn;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public double getTrafficResidue() {
        return trafficResidue;
    }

    public void setTrafficResidue(double trafficResidue) {
        this.trafficResidue = trafficResidue;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getVariables() {
        return variables;
    }

    public void setVariables(Map<String, String> variables) {
        this.variables = variables;
    }
}
```

And I need call getters in Thymeleaf

I tried

```
<label th:text="${currentUser.getMsisdn()}"/>
```

But it does not work. How can I call getters from model passed to Thymeleaf like parameter?

Comment: Post your controller code which returns the view page. Implement `toString()` in your POJO and see what does the `th:text="${currentUser}"` print? If it contains the property `msisdn` you should be able to access it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a standard getter method (in a format which Thymeleaf anticipates) then you can just mention objectName.fieldName instead of objectName.getFieldName(), though both will work. If your getter method has some non-standard name, then objectName.fieldName will not work, you have to use objectName.yourweirdGetterMethodName().

In your case, for the field msisdn, you have a standard getter method getMsisdn(). So, both `<label th:text="${currentUser.msisdn}"/>` and `<label th:text="${currentUser.getMsisdn()}"/>` should work just fine for you.

Again,
`<label th:text="${currentUser.msisdn}"/>` will work just fine, you don't have to explicitly mention the getter method (since its a standard getter method).

Unfortunately, both this options doesn't work for you. So that essentially means, problem is somewhere else. I doubt the objects that you added ever made to the view. If you can post the controller code, I may be able to help you out.

Comment: Cannot resolve 'msisdn' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Validates unresolved references and invalid expressions

Comment: <label th:text="${currentUser.msisdn}"/>

Comment: It work. But my IntellijIDEA underlines  this variables but it work

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using the getter for the value you are use the attribute directly
"${currentUser.msisdn}"
Or if you want some logic to be added to getter and use it you can refer here: [How to call object's method from Thymeleaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28067861/how-to-call-objects-method-from-thymeleaf)